# How to reterive order id from self develop block

Tags: magento2

I have developed a block and placed at order details page, and wanna get the order information but cannot use query_string

```
http://127.0.0.1/Magento2EE/sales/order/view/order_id/3/
```

I can get the order no. from `query_string`:
    `$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');`

For security issue I cannot use this method -> pass by query_string.

So, I try to use
`$this->getOrder()->getOrderId();`

but system retured error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrderId() on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,You need to check ,the order is exit or not by below code:

```
if($this->getOrder()->getId()):
 $orderId=$this->getOrder()->getId();
 $IncrementId=$this->getOrder()->getIncreamentId();

endif;
```

**getOrderId() is not  right method to get order id**